# Remove classes when scrolling to top

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a jquery code to add classes while scrolling on front page. I have few blocks which will have animated effect on scroll. Animations are fine when scrolling from top to bottom but the same happens when scrolling from bottom to top also. How can I prevent animation effects when scrolling from bottom to top?

```js
+function ($) {

var $animation_elements = $('.show-animate');
    var $window = $(window);

    function check_if_in_view() {
        var window_height = $window.height();
        var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
        var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

        $.each($animation_elements, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            //check to see if this current container is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('animated zoomIn');
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('animated zoomIn');
            }
        });

        var $image_elements = $('#views-bootstrap-latest-at-un-geneva-block-1 .row');
        $.each($image_elements, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            //check to see if this current container is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('animated pulse');
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('animated pulse');
            }
        });

        var $image_elements = $('.block-views-blockfront-page-bottom-block-block-1 .group-left');
        $.each($image_elements, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            //check to see if this current container is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
            }
        });
        var $image_elements = $('.block-views-blockfront-page-bottom-block-block-1 .group-right');
        $.each($image_elements, function() {
            var $element = $(this);
            var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
            var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
            var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

            //check to see if this current container is within viewport
            if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
                (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
                $element.addClass('animated fadeInRight');
            } else {
                $element.removeClass('animated fadeInRight');
            }
        });
    }

    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
    $window.trigger('scroll');
 
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: On the `.on("scroll")` event, you can get the values from the past `.offset.top()` and compare it to the actual offset.top. If the actual is bigger than before, do the animations, otherwise, don't

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check first the direction of scroll, you could try:

Changing

`$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);`

to:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     check_if_in_view
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Heres a [basic fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj0nasj0/1/) to show it in action.